# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem receiving data from api with all other links it was ok but that one is so hard .. So here is the code

```
$.ajax({
url: 'proxy.php?url=https://na.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/NA1/26667724?api_key=xxxx',
dataType:"json",
success: function() {
alert("Success");
},
error: function() {
console.log("Error")
}
});
```

And this is the  php code that i am using .

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
if (!isset($_GET['url'])) {
   die(); 
}
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$url = 'https://' . str_replace('https://', '', $url); 
echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

On the console log  is displayed --->XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Install/xampp/htdocs/allInOne/proxy.php?url=https://na.api.pvp.n…pectatorGameInfo/NA1/26667724?api_key=xxx. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @ jquery-1.11.3.js:9664jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.3.js:9215jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.11.3.js:9361jQuery.extend.getJSON @ jquery-1.11.3.js:9344renderInfo @ render.js:89onclick @ index.html:15
render.js:85   Error

Comment: Have you checked manually, what `proxy.php` returns? my guess is, that there is some kind of html error message there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error is in the proxy.php file, it cannot use file_get_contents because the url returns 404.

and the php echoes

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(https://euw.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/EUW1/19496550?api_key=xxxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\proxy.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

and when the javascript tries to read the response it fails.

Maybe this url is wrong?
https://euw.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/EUW1/19496550?api_keyxxx
**EDIT**

remove

```
headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:": "*",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':"X-Requested-With",},
crossDomain: true,
```

and change

```
dataType:"jsonp",
```

to

```
dataType:"json",
```

crossdomain requests only needed in javascript, when you are requesting data from a url with Php this rule wont be needed

**EDIT2**
The porblem was loading the html file directly be clicking, thus making it give the error for the cross origin policy.
Fixed by address the file from xamp

Comment: sec  i will provide new url

Comment: donenew  url  same error

Comment: the proxy.php is in the same domain as the ajax file?
if it is then you should change dataType:"jsonp" to dataType:"json",

And remove
headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:": "*",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':"X-Requested-With",},
crossDomain: true,

Comment: @ BinaryGhost now i get thiss --->Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Yep, you dont need cross domain requests when your are requesting the data with php. Is it working now?

Comment: the log still displays error  :X...

Comment: How are you trying to load the html file? directly by clicking on it? or by using xamp. For example http://localhost/allInOne/HTMLFILENAME.html
You wont be able to proccess the request if you just double click on the html...

Comment: It workt  TY very mutch  you are the best in the world  ^_^_^_^_^_^

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8")
```

with

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
//....................................................^You miss this ';'
```

Comment: Still not the solution but  ty :D

Comment: @QQstuf What is the error now?

Comment: The same . The error is for the first "<"  in the php file

Comment: @QQstuf I think error was in the url you passed to the PHP file...

Comment: the current url probably   is forbiden or something .. the  data  depend whether or not the player with this id is  in game  if he  is there is data if he is not there is error .. . but the error that i  have is not related  to this

Answer (score -1):

Your Header line is

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8")
```

My header line is

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
```